# Como simular shift + click em python

Tags: python, teclado, eventos-do-mouse, winapi, pyautogui

Galera, alguem sabe como simular um shift + click?

O objetivo deste código é que o a keyboard Shift se mantenha ativada durante o clique que será executado nas coordenadas (x,y).

Não precisa necessariamente utilizar do pyautogui ou win32api. Pode ser qualquer tipo de solução que consiga simular um clique enquanto o shift está pressionado.

O problema atual é que o shift e o clique é executado, porém não são executados ao mesmo tempo ou o shift não permanece quando o comando click é executado. Tentei utilizar um while(pyautogui.keyDown('shift') e o comando shift estava sendo executado porém dentro disto o clique não era executado.

Estou tentando de varias formas com keyup keydown (até dentro da função click) e o shift sempre sai separado dos clicks:

```js
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *
import time
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y,andar): #single click, u can swich andar to do a right or left click 
        if(andar):

            win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,0,0)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,0,0)
            print('right click')
            
            
        else:

            win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
            print('left click')

while(True):
      if  pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:\\xxx\\shiftclick_here.png', confidence=0.8) != None:
            pyautogui.keyDown('shiftleft')
            click(1585, 548, False)#click at where i want
            pyautogui.keyUp('shiftleft')
            time.sleep(0.01)
```

---

Explicando o código:
A def click é apenas uma função para executar o click na coordenada que eu quero sem necessariamente especificar a todo momento a coordenada, funciona como um encurtador de código sempre que eu quero clicar.

O while(True) está em loop analisando se uma imagem (shiftclick_here.png) na minha tela está presente, caso esteja presente ele executa a função de clicar na coordenada que essa imagem SEMPRE aparece.

O clique funciona perfeitamente, mas a combinação com o shift não está funcionando da forma que deveria, ou seja, ao mesmo tempo.

Já procurei pelo Stack outros tópicos sobre o assunto, tentei aplicar uma correção no meu porém não tive nenhum sucesso...

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar `pyautogui.keydown('shift')` e depois o click